# How do I write the specification for a generic instantiation?

Tags: generics, ada

I'll start with the classic example of a generic procedure in Ada:

```ada
-------------------------
--  swaps.ads
-------------------------
package Swaps is
  generic
    type E is private;
  procedure Generic_Swap (Left, Right : in out E);
end Swaps;
```

```ada
-------------------------
--  swaps.adb
-------------------------
package body Swaps is
  procedure Generic_Swap (Left, Right : in out E) is
    Temporary : E;
  begin
    Temporary := Left;
    Left := Right;
    Right := Temporary;
  end Generic_Swap;
end Swaps;
```

Now suppose I want to implement a specialized `String_Swap` procedure for swapping strings, and provide it to all users of my package.  I can add the following to the body declaration in `swaps.adb`:

```ada
procedure String_Swap is new Generic_Swap (String);
```

However, if I add nothing to the specification in `swaps.ads`, then no package can use this procedure.  For example:

```ada
-------------------------
--  main.adb
-------------------------
with Swaps; use Swaps;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Main is
   First  : String := "world!";
   Second : String := "Hello, ";
begin
   String_Swap (First, Second); -- #Error: String_Swap is undefined#
   Put_Line (First);
   Put_Line (Second);
end Main;
```

I've tried to add the type of the procedure in to the specification:

```ada
procedure String_Swap (Left, Right : in out String);
```

but then Ada complains that this specification has a missing body and that the definition in `swaps.adb` conflicts with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use your generic for type `String` because it is an unconstrained type.  But lets use `Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String` instead.

What you have to do is:

1. Publish a specification of a suitable procedure in the package specification.
2. Implement the public procedure with a call to the internally instantiated generic procedure.

```ada
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

package Swaps is
   generic
      type Element_Type is private;
   procedure Generic_Swap (Left, Right : in out Element_Type);

   procedure Swap (Left, Right : in out Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);
end Swaps;
```

```ada
package body Swaps is

   procedure Generic_Swap (Left, Right : in out Element_Type) is
      Temporary : Element_Type;
   begin
      Temporary := Left;
      Left      := Right;
      Right     := Temporary;
   end Generic_Swap;

   procedure Swap_Unbounded_Strings is
     new Generic_Swap (Element_Type => Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);

   procedure Swap (Left, Right : in out Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String) is
   begin
      Swap_Unbounded_Strings (Left  => Left,
                              Right => Right);
   end Swap;
end Swaps;
```

But in general, I prefer to keep instantiations of generics completely separate from the specifications and implementations of those generics.

Comment: Note that, instead of a procedure that calls the instantiation, you can also use a renaming-as-body to implement Swap: `procedure Swap (Left, Right : in out Ada.Strings.Unbounded_String) renames Swap_Unbounded_Strings;`

Comment: Looks like I left out an `Unbounded`: should be `Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;`.

Answer (score 4):

The way I would address this is to use a child package:

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

package Swaps.Instances is
   procedure Swap is new Generic_Swap (Element => Character);
   procedure Swap is new Generic_Swap (Element => Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
   ...
end Swaps.Instances;
```

Note that it's possible to write a generic that will handle indefinite types:

```
generic
   type Element (<>) is private;
```

and change the body of `Generic_Swap` to

```
procedure Generic_Swap (Left, Right : in out Element) is
   Temp : constant Element := Left;
begin -- Generic_Swap
   Left := Right;
   Right := Temp;
end Generic_Swap;
```

but to use it the actual objects must either be unconstrained or have the same subtype.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that a user of `Swaps` can see is the spec. Since there is nothing about `String_Swap` in the spec, no amount of fiddling in the package *body* will make any difference.

If you wanted to "implement a specialized `String_Swap` procedure for swapping strings", you would have to include it in the spec:

```ada
package Swaps is
   generic
      type E is private;
   procedure Generic_Swap(Left, Right : in out E);
   procedure String_Swap is new Generic_Swap(String);
end Swaps;
```

This turns out to be a bad example: when compiled with `-gnatl`, we get

```ada
 1. package Swaps is
 2.    generic
 3.       type E is private;
 4.    procedure Generic_Swap(Left, Right : in out E);
 5.    procedure String_Swap is new Generic_Swap(String);
                                                 |
    >>> actual for "E" must be a definite subtype

 6. end Swaps;
```

This is because the type `String` is indefinite, that is, a particular `String` has a particular length, and can only be assigned to another `String` (or slice of a `String`) of the same length; so even if your procedure `Main` was written out without using the generic, it would fail with a constraint error at runtime. Check out `Ada.Strings.Unbounded` at [ARM A.4.5](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-5.html).

So, try with a definite type:

```ada
package Swaps is
   generic
      type E is private;
   procedure Generic_Swap(Left, Right : in out E);
   procedure Character_Swap is new Generic_Swap(Character);
end Swaps;
```

Unfortunately,

```ada
 1. package Swaps is
 2.    generic
 3.       type E is private;
 4.    procedure Generic_Swap(Left, Right : in out E);
 5.    procedure Character_Swap is new Generic_Swap(Character);
       |
    >>> warning: cannot instantiate "Generic_Swap" before body seen
    >>> warning: Program_Error will be raised at run time

 6. end Swaps;
```

The solution has to be to instantiate separately: perhaps at library level,

```ada
with Swaps;
procedure Character_Swap is new Swaps.Generic_Swap(Character);
```

It’s going to be a lot easier to leave it up to your users to instantiate the generic as they wish.

Comment: So is your conclusion that it's not possible to define `Generic_Swap(Character)` within the package and expose it to all users of the package?

Comment: You could create a package of instantiations, with the generic package as a child package. The generic package can then be hidden from users, or they can "with/use" it if they need to make additional instantiations.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried to add the type of the procedure in to the specification:
>
> ```ada
> procedure String_Swap (Left, Right : in out String);
> ```
>
> but then Ada complains that this specification has a missing body and that the definition in swaps.adb conflicts with it.

This is good idea, but instantiation can't complete a procedure declaration (and compiler says that). What you need is use a procedure renaming:

```ada
   procedure String_Swap_Inst is new Generic_Swap (String);

   procedure String_Swap (Left, Right : in out String)
     renames String_Swap_Inst;
```

Also, to be able to use String with your generic, you need change it a little to allow unconstrained types:

```ada
package Swaps is
   generic
      type E (<>) is private;
   procedure Generic_Swap (Left, Right : in out E);

   procedure String_Swap (Left, Right : in out String);
end Swaps;

package body Swaps is
  procedure Generic_Swap (Left, Right : in out E) is
    Temporary : E := Left;
  begin
    Left := Right;
    Right := Temporary;
   end Generic_Swap;

   procedure String_Swap_Inst is new Generic_Swap (String);

   procedure String_Swap (Left, Right : in out String)
     renames String_Swap_Inst;
end Swaps;
```

And of course you can swap this way only string of equal length, otherwise you will get a Constraint_Error just like in  an assignment:

```ada
X : String (1 .. 2) := "123";  --  Constraint_Error!!!
```